# Input audio device disabled

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, system-settings

When I boot my PC, that has front and rear mic jacks, and a mic plugged into the rear mic jack, the rear microphone is listed as device, but it is greyed out (see screenshot). The microphone in Skype does not work.
[image]
More info obtained by typing `unity-control-center sound` from the command line

```
(unity-control-center:21290): sound-cc-panel-WARNING **: Unable to find stream for bar '(null)'

(unity-control-center:21290): sound-cc-panel-WARNING **: active_output_update - couldn't find a stream from the supposed active output

(unity-control-center:21290): sound-cc-panel-WARNING **: active_input_update - couldn't find a stream from the supposed active input
```

I have `pavucontrol` installed. There, the microphone works, the sound bar properly moves when there is sound.

I tried to unplug and plug the microphone again. It is not greyed out any more in GNOME settings, but it still does not work in Skype.

My PC can boot in Fedora as well, and Fedora has no problems: the device is not greyed out at startup and Skype works.

Why does the device start up greyed out?

I'm running Ubuntu 16.10 with kernel 4.8.0-42-generic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the exact same problem.
To solve it I installed pavucontrol:

```
sudo apt-get install pavucontrol
```

Then I opened (Super key and type pavucontrol, then enter) and in the input section there was the mic and it was working. So I moved the volumes up and pres the "set as fall-back" button and then it appeared on audio option. 
Sorry my bad english, hope it works for you.

Comment: pavucontrol's "set as fall-back" button did the trick, thank you